# Install telegram-bot-api

Tags: telegram-bot

I want to install this, but it gives an error. What is the problem?

https://tdlib.github.io/telegram-bot-api/build.html

error:

```
make\[2\]: \*\*\* \[td/CMakeFiles/tdcore.dir/build.make:1818: td/CMakeFiles/tdcore.dir/td/telegram/MessagesManager.cpp.o\] Error 137
make\[2\]: \*\*\* Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make\[1\]: \*\*\* \[CMakeFiles/Makefile2:517: td/CMakeFiles/tdcore.dir/all\] Error 2
make: \*\*\* \[Makefile:130: all\] Error 2
```

The server has 2GB of RAM and a 2-core processor, but it still didn't work. Could the problem be due to low RAM?